# Tensor algebra derivation

Tags: tensors

With $\delta^\mu_\nu$ the Kronecker delta, all indices running from $0$ to $3$, $g_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$, and $\delta^\mu_\mu =g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu}=4$, I am unable to show that

$$
D_{\nu\lambda}\left[ -\big( k^2-m^2  \big)g^{\mu\nu}+k^\mu k^\nu   \right]=\delta^\mu_\lambda
$$

leads to

$$
D_{\nu\lambda}=\dfrac{-g_{\nu\lambda}+\big(k_\nu k_\lambda\big)/m^2}{k^2-m^2}~~.
$$

My intuition is to set $\lambda\to\mu$ so that $\delta^\mu_\lambda=4$ giving

$$
D_{\nu\lambda}\left[ -\big( k^2-m^2  \big)g^{\lambda\nu}+k^\lambda k^\nu \right]=4~~,
$$

but here I become lost.  Maybe I should multiply both sides by $g_{\lambda\nu}$, and I should probably complete a square or something to get that $m^4$ term floating around, but I am not seeing it.  Any tips?  Thanks.

Comment: it looks like you have to multiply by two fully contravariant metric tensors to get both $k$ vectors to be contravariant as in your target formula

Comment: @tired yes, I see that.  My problem is that three terms have $D$ in it at the beginning and only two have $D$ in it at the end, and I forgot the trick, which I used to know when I showed this before.  Do you know what the trick is?  Can doing two contractions help me with that part?  I only see that helping achieve the requisite $k_\mu k_\nu$ term.

Answer (score 1):

The solution comes from an ansatz $D_{\nu\lambda}=Ag_{\nu\lambda}+Bk_\nu k_\lambda$.